# My account was automatically unregistered after I completed my registration with Stack Exchange

Tags: support, user-accounts, moderators, unregistered-users

As I was upvoting a comment, the UI said to complete registration. After completing registration, a new account was created, and my existing account was unregistered...
Now I can't upvote the answer from the previous account. Can a moderator help me have access to the old account again so?

This was the original question: *[How to measure cost savings from consolidation transactions?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/118106/how-to-measure-cost-savings-from-consolidation-transactions)*

The merge tool seems broken even though I included the other profile link...

[image]

Comment: The profiles need to be on the same site. So if anything I would expect you use `https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/141923/coinselector23` and `https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/141867/coinselector23` but the duplicate explains the process better.

Comment: If the merge tool dosen't help. maybe try the contact link to let someone take a look. visibility at the level of accounts will need staff

Comment: I realized that profiles weren't from the same site. However the merge tool was broken when I merged on the same site too. The site staff help me. Thanks all!